# JUnit test case passing in Eclipse but failing in gradle

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, junit

I have a Junit test case which if I run from Eclipse -> Junit, it passes but if I do the gradle build, the same test case fails.Even if do "Coverage" in Eclipse, then also it fails.

```
public void mytest() {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(JsonConverter.class);
    when(jsonConverter.fromJson()).thenThrow(Some Exception);
    when(jsonConverter.fromJson()).thenCallRealmethod();
    //and some further code
}
```

Comment: post your whole test class.

Comment: further code is taking user input and calling the method.Test case fails at the above lines only.

Comment: do you have `setup()` and `teardown()` methods?

Comment: How does it fail? What is the error or failure?

Comment: JsonConverter is becoming null

Comment: If you disable all other tests and run the gradle build does it pass?

Comment: How to you ensure that it is not null?

Comment: Its a class hence it will not be null

Comment: where do you initialize the variable jsonConverter (note lower case "j")? PowerMockito.mockStatic(JsonConverter.class); initializes JsonConverter with upper case "J"